# How to handle an event dispatched by a Firefox add-on?

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, firefox-addon

I installed [TST-plugin for Firefox 29.0](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/). It's perfect for me almost in full, but there is some option I wanna change.

When I close the current tab, TST focuses on the left tab. I wish, it focuses on previous in history of last opened tab after closing current (like Ctrl+Tab).

[As developers said](http://piro.sakura.ne.jp/xul/_treestyletab.html.en#api-focus), I should catch their event, prevent it and... what? Snippet provided by the developer:

```
window.addEventListener(
  "TreeStyleTabFocusNextTab",
  function(aEvent) {
    if (Prefs.getCharPref('myextension.focus.mode') != 'default')
      aEvent.preventDefault();
  },
  false
);
```

I don't know, what I should do and even there I should do this. Where can I write the code to catch events? How can I dispatch ctrl+tab event to TST and only after that close the current tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TST developer put up the docs for other extension developers that like to modify or interact with TST, not for "regular" users. You'd have to write your add-on, where you'd use the code snippet you referenced in an overlay script to `browser.js`.

I had a fast look at the code of the add-on itself, to check if there is an equivalent preference to control this without writing code, but and *EDIT* there is one: `browser.tabs.selectOwnerOnClose`. See `onFocusNextTab` in `modules/window.js`... Not sure if it is exposed in the add-on preferences window anywhere... But you can use `about:config` (open this in a tab) to set it to `true` (you might have to create it first in about:config as a Boolean preference).

So your options here are:

- Use the preference.
- Modify the add-on itself (`_tryMoveFocusFromClosingCurrentTab` in `modules/browser.js` from what I gather).
- Write a short XUL-overlay add-on that uses the snippet the TST author proposes in a `browser.xul` overlay script.

If you decide to change/write add-on code yourself, see [firefox-addon](/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) info page and section for further information.